# Select com JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

Como limito esta consulta para listar apenas um registro de imagem?

Tenho a tabela de imóveis e a tabela de fotos, a tabela de imoveis possui vários registros, e cada registro possui varias fotos, porem quando executo o select, ele leva em consideração a quantidade de fotos que o imóvel possui, eu preciso que seja mostrado apenas uma foto por imóvel

```
SELECT * FROM imovel JOIN imagem ON id_imagem_imovel = id_imovel ORDER BY id_imovel DESC
```

A estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE `imagem` (
  `id_foto` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_imagem_imovel` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `foto` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `imagem` (`id_foto`, `id_imagem_imovel`, `foto`) VALUES
(12, 6, '6_383_27_01_2017_1485520949.jpg'),
(13, 7, '7_396_27_01_2017_1485521179.jpg'),
(14, 7, '7_403_27_01_2017_1485521179.jpg'),
(15, 7, '7_410_27_01_2017_1485521179.jpg'),
(16, 7, '7_417_27_01_2017_1485521179.jpg'),
(17, 7, '7_424_27_01_2017_1485521179.jpg'),
(18, 5, '5_429_27_01_2017_1485522171.jpeg'),
(20, 1, '1_434_27_01_2017_1485523016.jpeg'),
(21, 1, '1_435_27_01_2017_1485523016.jpeg'),
(22, 1, '1_436_27_01_2017_1485523016.jpeg'),
(23, 1, '1_437_27_01_2017_1485523016.jpeg'),
(24, 4, '4_441_27_01_2017_1485523040.jpg');



CREATE TABLE `imovel` (
  `id_imovel` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome_proprietario` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `telefone_proprietario` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `endereco_imovel` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_tipo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_cidade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_bairro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `finalidade` enum('Alugar','Comprar') NOT NULL,
  `dormitorios` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `suites` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `banheiros` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `garagem` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descricao` text,
  `banner` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `destaque` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dt_cadastro` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `imovel` (`id_imovel`, `nome_proprietario`, `telefone_proprietario`, `endereco_imovel`, `id_tipo`, `id_cidade`, `id_bairro`, `finalidade`, `dormitorios`, `suites`, `banheiros`, `garagem`, `area`, `valor`, `descricao`, `banner`, `destaque`, `dt_cadastro`) VALUES
(1, '', '', '', 1, 1, 1, 'Alugar', 3, 1, 2, 2, 100, '250000.00', 'Primeiro imóvel cadastrado.', 0, 1, '2017-01-23 19:30:37'),
(4, 'MARCOS', '', 'Rua , 286', 3, 1, 3, 'Comprar', 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '1500.00', 'Descrição aqui', 1, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(5, 'PAULO ', '31989820602', 'Rua , 286', 3, 1, 4, 'Comprar', 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, '5222.00', 'Descrição aqui', 1, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(6, 'MARCOS PAULO ', '31989820602', 'Rua , 286', 3, 1, 4, 'Comprar', 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, '5222.00', 'Descrição aqui', 1, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(7, 'MARCOS PAULO ', '31989820602', 'Rua , 286', 3, 1, 4, 'Comprar', 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, '5222.00', 'Descrição aqui', 1, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

Comment: acrecente `LIMIT 1` no final da sua query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `limit`, assim:

```
SELECT *
FROM imovel JOIN imagem ON id_imagem_imovel = id_imovel
ORDER BY id_imovel DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Creio que se quer mostrar multiplos imóveis pode usar GROUP by:

```
SELECT *
FROM imovel JOIN imagem ON id_imagem_imovel = id_imovel
GROUP by id_imovel
ORDER BY id_imovel DESC
```

Para que imóveis sem foto sejam listados, troque `JOIN` por `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM imovel LEFT JOIN imagem ON id_imagem_imovel = id_imovel
GROUP by id_imovel
ORDER BY id_imovel DESC
```

Como explicado em:

- [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/3635)

Comment: Assim ele ira me listar apenas um imovel, e não a listagem de todos os imoveis e cada imovel com apenas uma foto

Comment: Ok, vou editar e inserir

Comment: Assim listou, porem se estiver sem imagem não aparece, teria como listar ate os que não tem imagem?

Comment: Show, testei aqui e deu certo com LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Tu podes fazer um `JOIN` a partir dum `subselect`:

```
SELECT * FROM imovel 
JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id_imagem_imovel FROM imagem 
    GROUP BY id_imagem_imovel
) AS imagem ON imagem.id_imagem_imovel = imovel.id_imovel 
ORDER BY imovel.id_imovel DESC
```

Desta forma, ele agrupará as imagens pelo `id` do `imovel` e após isso aplicará o `JOIN`

Comment: assim sera que não fica mais pesado para vários resultados?